# How to retrieve product list in json format based on category id?

Tags: json, magento

I want to retrieve a list of products through category id in JSON format.

Like http://magentohost/json/prod.php?catID=8 [This is not a reference link. It shows what the link should look like.]

Comment: I cannot view your link

Comment: Sorry for that!
It's just to show that how it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution from Magento SOAP API for this.

Refer the following link.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignedProducts.html